# Top bar margin is displayed wrong after update to 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, top-bar

After updating to 20.04, my top bar is displayed wrong. The icons seem to have correct size, but the bar itself seems to be too thin. Using maximized windows, e.g. hitting the close-button actually hits top bar icons. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 with gnome version 3.36.2
As theme I use Adapta (applications) and Adwaita (icons), but changing it does not make any difference. Only when choose a different display scaling to other than 100% (like e.g. 125%) lets the error disappear. Changing scaling back to 100% also means wrong top bar scaling again.
How do I get this solved?

[image]

Edit:

```
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
drwxr-xr-x 5 dominik dominik 4096 Feb 16 12:22 .
drwx------ 3 dominik dominik 4096 Jun 23 10:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 dominik dominik 4096 Feb 16 12:19 ShellTile@emasab.it
drwxr-xr-x 3 dominik dominik 4096 Feb 16 12:22 wintile@nowsci.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 dominik dominik 4096 Feb 16 12:19 wintitle@megh

$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 22 16:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mai 22 11:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 14 19:20 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mai 22 11:37 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 22 15:12 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating from 18.04. Changing the GNOME Shell theme solved the problem. You will need to install:

- GNOME Tweak Tool

> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

- [User Theme extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)

Then just download any gnome shell theme (Arc Theme worked for me) and choose it in the tweak tool. Hope this helps.