# Ubuntu 20.04 Display scale for top bar is broken after nvidia driver update

Tags: drivers, gnome, 20.04, display

Not sure how to fix this, haven't found any solutions after looking at these [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252767/top-bar-margin-is-displayed-wrong-after-update-to-20-04) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125662/how-to-reset-gnome-panel) [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191638/graphics-and-resolution-problems-nvidia-in-ubuntu-18-04-after-update) related topics. I recently updated my nvidia driver from 395 to 435 and it changed my display settings. I tried to uninstall with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and reinstall the drivers. I even tried to revert back to driver 395, but that didn't work either. Here's what my top bar looks like after every reboot.

[image]

and this is what it looked like before the driver update.

[image]

When I go into Display settings and change the scaling from 100% to 200% than revert the changes I get the top bar back to normal like in the 2nd picture. This change doesn't save so once I reboot it goes back to the large appearance. It's really annoying and I have no idea how to fix it. I would appreciate any help with this, thank you in advance.

Comment: Check here for an explanation of the issue (a bug in libmutter library, some people have small fonts, other big fonts) and workarounds: https://askubuntu.com/q/1269090/1037999 Currently, only workarounds are available until libmutter package is fixed and released.

Comment: I recently updated and the problem has been fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how i got it resolved. Rather a workaround than a solution, though.

Open a text editor and add following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.99
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1
```

In the second line enter whatever value you usually use. Save it as a .sh script (eg. somename.sh) and set it as executable in permissions dialog in file browser (check mark at 'Allow executing file as program'.

Then open the program Startup Applications and add an entry. In the `command` field enter the path to the .sh file (like `/home/USERNAME/somefolder/somename.sh`).

So basically what it does is set and reset the font scaling which makes the top bar display the size that you intended.

Comment: thanks for the workaround. I'm still hoping someone will be able to help me fix this without a workaround.